# Cypress: automatic tests for credit card payment

Tags: wordpress, automated-tests, cypress

I am doing the automatic test for payment by credit card. Unfortunately the test fails me in the Expiry Date item

my code:

```
    cy.getWithinIframe('[name="cardnumber"]').type('4242424242424242');
    cy.getWithinIframe('[name="exp-date"]').type('122024');
    cy.getWithinIframe('[name="cvc"]').type('987');
```

gives following errors:

[image]

where the test ends

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So for iframes, we have to look for workarounds as cypress doesn't provide out of the box support for iframes.

**1.** We will create a custom command which will help us to traverse through iframes and also helps in code reusability.
Under `cypress/support/command.js` write:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', (iframe) => {
    return cy.get(iframe)
        .its('0.contentDocument.body')
        .should('be.visible')
        .then(cy.wrap);
})
```

**2.** I saw that the tests are randomly failing sometimes, so it would be good if we use the [retry option from cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries.html). For that go to `cypress.json` and write:

`"retries": 2`

This option will only work with cypress v5.0 and above.

**3.** In your test file,
for inputting **card number** use:

```
cy.getIframe('#stripe-card-element > .__PrivateStripeElement > iframe').click().type('4242 4242 4242 4242')
```

for inputting **expiry date** use:

```
cy.getIframe('#stripe-exp-element > .__PrivateStripeElement > iframe').click().type('0921')
```

for inputting **CVC Number** use:

```
cy.getIframe('#stripe-cvc-element > .__PrivateStripeElement > iframe').click().type('123')
```

Comment: All the time I tried getting into the iframe and then finding the specific input element once inside and never could get it working. Bluntly click & type - clean and awesome! Thank you so much for sharing this! Using this for Shopify Bogus payment method.

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same issue, using that same method (https://medium.com/@michabahr/testing-stripe-elements-with-cypress-5a2fc17ab27b).

The problem is that the expired date and the cvv inputs are in separeted iframes, maybe due to the personalization. So you have to specify in which iframe your iframe is:

```
cy.getWithinIframe('[name="cardnumber"]').type("4242424242424242");
cy.get('iframe')
    .eq(1)
    .iframeLoaded()
    .its('document')
    .getInDocument('[name="exp-date"]')
    .type('1225');

cy.get('iframe')
    .eq(2)
    .iframeLoaded()
    .its('document')
    .getInDocument('[name="cvc"]')
    .type('123');
```

Comment: It works perfect in magento 2.3 stripe oficial plugin, just take the command for the link provided

Answer (score 1):

To others: I got the exact same error as @Gianmarco Gagliardi

I then followed @Alapan Das three steps but still got the same error.

What worked for me was to click the iframe first with a modified version of @alapan Das' solution, adding force: true to click regardless of focus:

```
// yes, i have to type the whole cardnumber after click
cy.getIframe('iframe').click({ force: true }).type('4242424242424242')
cy.getWithinIframe('[name="cardnumber"]').type('4242424242424242');
```

I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

The technical answers provided above are excellent. But, first and foremost, I'd like to take a step back.

Why even try to test it in Cypress? In terms of QA, we shouldn't test integrations in e2e; instead, integration tests should be performed at a lower level - integration level. Here, we could just mock the provider's response and continue with how our app would react to it.